# Create a file when the command succeed. Create another when it fails. One line?

Tags: bash

In Bash, I want to create a file when the command succeed, otherwise create another file. Something along the line of

```
if `my command`; then
  touch command.complete
else
  touch command.fail
fi
```

Is it possible to write this in one line?

Comment: Yes, but why?  Are lines a scarce resource?  Oh, and I don't think you want the backticks around `my command`; the code you've written will take the output of `my command` and treat it as a command to be executed.

Comment: The one-line question was just because I thought something as simple as this should be able to fit into one line. Not really important.

Comment: In my opinion, the `if/else/fi` version is *much* clearer than any of the alternative that have been offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases this will do:

```
my.command && touch command.complete || touch command.failed
```

The corner case is, thanks to @uzsolt, when `touch complete` itself can fail. Then `touch failed` is executed. In case the difference matters, you can use this one:

```
my.command && (touch command.complete || true) || touch command.failed
```

Comment: Fail! If `touch command.complete` fails, `touch command.failed` will run!

Try `echo a && touch /x || echo b` (without write permissions to /)

Comment: @uzsolt: TNX, adapted my post.